# сохранение результата выборки в mysql

Tags: mysql

создал следующий запрос

```
SELECT theme, second_name, first_name 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT reader_key, theme_key 
      FROM Books_giving 
      NATURAL JOIN Books) AS it 
NATURAL JOIN Readers 
NATURAL JOIN Themes
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT reader_key, theme_key 
             FROM Books_giving 
             NATURAL JOIN Books) AS nt 
       NATURAL JOIN Readers AS nReaders 
       WHERE it.theme_key = nt.theme_key 
         AND LEFT(Readers.second_name, 1) = LEFT(nReaders.second_name, 1) 
         AND LEFT(Readers.first_name, 1) = LEFT(nReaders.first_name, 1) 
         AND nt.reader_key <> it.reader_key) >= 1
```

проблема в дублировании одного и того же запроса в двух местах:
в таком случае:

```
SELECT theme, second_name, first_name 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT reader_key, theme_key 
      FROM Books_giving 
      NATURAL JOIN Books) AS it 
NATURAL JOIN Readers 
NATURAL JOIN Themes
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM it AS nReaders 
       WHERE it.theme_key = nt.theme_key 
         AND LEFT(Readers.second_name, 1) = LEFT(it.second_name, 1) 
         AND LEFT(Readers.first_name, 1) = LEFT(it.first_name, 1) 
         AND nt.reader_key <> it.reader_key) >= 1
```

говорит о несуществовании таблицы под именем it

```
Table 'lab.it' doesn't exist
```

можно ли вынести результат запроса в переменную или вроде того?
версия mysql - 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2

таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [WITH Syntax (Common Table Expressions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)

Comment: мне кажется запрос можно сильно упростить и повторное использование подзапроса вообще не понадобится. Но так как вы не привели структуру таблиц и из за natural join и не использования алиасов во всех сравнениях ее невозможно понять по самому запросу, помочь вам не представляется возможным

Comment: @Akina, версии недостаточно

Comment: @almostAI В вашей версии никак этот it использовать повторно не написав его невозможно. Но очень может быть есть другие пути

Comment: @Mike, добавил таблицы

Comment: кто-нибудь имеет варианты?

Comment: Переменные не пробовали использовать?(в MySQL в запросах можно создавать\изменять переменные)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что здача вывести темы книг и людей их читающих в случае если на теме есть два (и более) человек с одинаковыми инициалами ?

Comment: @Mike, да, именно

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, на любой версии актуальны?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, видимо они не предназначены для хранения таблиц

Comment: @almostAI Переменные позволяют лишь протащить сохраненное значение из одной строки в строку, которая в выборке идет позже и там их сопоставлять. В данном случае применения им не видно

Comment: @Mike, я сильно не вчитывался в сам запрос, увидел что второй запрос считает кол-во, и предложил переменную, но незаметил что там дополнительно идет огромный фильтр.
@almostAI На версиях 5.3 и выше точно есть, и да таблицы они хранить не могут. Зато таблицы могут хранить `временные таблицы`(тафталогия но что поделаеш)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю запрос можно упростить примерно так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT theme, second_name, first_name
  FROM Books_giving 
NATURAL JOIN Readers 
NATURAL JOIN Themes
 WHERE (theme_key, LEFT(second_name, 1), LEFT(first_name, 1))
    IN (
         SELECT theme_key, LEFT(second_name, 1), LEFT(first_name, 1)
           FROM Books_giving 
        NATURAL JOIN Readers
        NATURAL JOIN Books
          GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
         HAVING count(distinct reader_key)>1
       )
```

Comment: запустил - результат не тот, сейчас проверю, что не так

Comment: само задание - Вывести список читателей у кого совпадают инициалы и совпадают вкусы по тематике
чтения.

Comment: @almostAI Ну как минимум я Books забыл в подзапросе, так что тему он брал видимо из основного запроса. Уже добавил. Сначала сам подзапрос выполните что бы он возвращал корректные темы и инициалы

Comment: спасибо, помогло, щас разберу